# How to split recyclerview columns automatically when height reached

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a list of buttons that creates a new column when there are too many buttons on the current column, something like `flex-wrap` in `css`, but vertically [(example)](https://jsfiddle.net/g9x03Lv8/).
how can I achieve that in recycler view?
And if it's impossible with recycler view how can I do it without recycler view? (I heard about [`FlexBoxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). would this work? and if so, how can I integrate it with RecyclerView?)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is also a `FlexboxLayoutManager` in the same library . read the [README.MD](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/README.md). It will work same .

Comment: wow thank you so mush this is what I searched for